# Writing multiple characters into a file, but only see one character? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write random numbers between one and zero, eighty times.
This should write 010100001010100101001010100101010.... whatever (80 times) into a txt file, but instead I get one single number. Why does

```
from random import random

bro = int(input('Amount: '))

for i in range(bro):
    open('e.txt', 'w').write(str(round(random())))
```

not work?

Comment: It's wasteful to reopen the same file for every write.  What you should do `open` it first, run the `for` loop, and then call `close()`.

Comment: `open('e.txt', 'w')` opens `e.txt` for writing and if there is anything in that file, deletes the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the file once and then write to the opened file. You can also use `randint(0, 1)` instead of `round(random())`:

```
from random import randint

amnt = 80

with open('e.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(amnt):
        f.write(str(randint(0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing `open('e.txt', 'w')` inside the `for` loop means that you're recreating the file on every iteration (i.e., clearing whatever contents it may hold).

Hence, when the program completes, the file will hold only the last piece of data written into it.

Comment: Thank you for _why_ it happened. Still need _how_ to fix it though. :l

Comment: @UnknownBobby: See the other answer; you need to use `a+` instead of `w` AFAIK.

Comment: Opening the file within the loop is the problem; not the mode. You only need to open the file once before the for loop.

Comment: @UnknownBobby: Ah yes, see the comment above. My answer actually **does** give you the full solution. You can `open('e.txt', 'w')` once before the loop, and that's it. No need to change the `'w'` mode.